# Adding multiple records to database from HTML form having some common parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql-server, jsp

I have a web page which has a 2 part form. Tech used: JSP, HTML, SQL server

In first part the user would enter some basic info which would be common for all records he is entering in the current bunch. Then on clicking next he would be redirected to a page where he can go on to add specific information for each record in the batch - with options to 'submit and add another record' (redirecting to same page, and only needing to enter the new record specific fields) or submit all records entered.

So I will need to constantly hold the parameters from the initial page and keep forming multiple 'objects' till the user clicks submit, which would call a method in JSP/JAVA class to insert the records.

**------Page 1 | Basic Information ------**

[image]

**------Page 2 | Per Record ------**

[image]

One way would be to keep forming and appending a query for each record and storing in a hidden field passed through the pages and pass through method on click of submit.

Can someone suggest a better method of how to handle such a situation?

Comment: I think the approach you are contemplating is complicated and prone to errors. What happens, for example if the user presses the back button? I would combine the parent data with the child data on the same web page allowing the user to enter and edit all data before pressing the Save button. You could then use jQuery/Ajax to verify and pass the parent and client data to the back-end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue is that there are some 5-20 records which would have the same parent data values, and I want to eliminate unnecessary re-entry. Any suggestion you have would be appreciated.

Comment: That is what I am saying. The parent data would be entered at the top of the form and a table beneath where all data related to the parent can be entered. You may wish to look at this jQuery data-table plugin  http://www.datatables.net/